# Database contains a site that is not found in the site map

Tags: 2013, 2016, upgrade

This error is in the upgrade log for mounting a copy of a content database in a different farm. This error is being thrown for one site collection (all other site collections are fine). This site is 100% functional in the original farm, but while mounting and going through the upgrade process, this error is thrown. Trying to view the site settings for the site shows a message of "We apologize for the inconvenience, but we've made OneDrive and sites read-only while we do some maintenance".

Source farm: SP 2013

Destination farm: 2016

Any thoughts on what might be going wrong in the upgrade process?

edit: found a bit more. there are multiple rows in the allsites table that reference the same site (different id, same url). The ULS logs captured the SQL error: it tried to run an insert into the dbo.sitemap table, but it had already inserted a row with the given url. This left two sites, with different IDs but the same URL in the database, but not in the site map, and thus the error. So this appears to be a classic case of an orphaned site.

Comment: If this site collection is in its own DB, can you check the DB upgrade status in 2013 Central admin to make sure that it does not need upgrading before it is migrated to 2016.

Comment: Upgrades will throw the site out if the URL is already taken. Happens all the time with clients with root sites. Also check `restore-spdeletedsite` and see if it is in there.